# Android Power Button Pressed to Close

Tags: android

I have an app that works perfect but when I press power button some activity variables lost their value. So I decided to close the app.  I am using BroadcastReceiver to close the app.

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (intentAction!=null){
        String myLog = "Unknown intent action";
        switch (intentAction){
            case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
                myLog = "Power Button Press SCREEN OFF";
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON:
                myLog = "Power Button Press SCREEN ON";
                break;
            case MY_BROADCAST:
                myLog = "Custom Broadcase Reveived";
                break;
        }
        if (myLog.equalsIgnoreCase("Power Button Press SCREEN OFF") || myLog.equalsIgnoreCase("Power Button Press SCREEN ON")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Close your app").setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Activity a = (Activity) context;
                    a.finish();
                }
            });
            Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
    }
}
```

**In Activity onCreate ...**

```
private MyPowerReceiver mReceiver = new MyPowerReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                mReceiver, new IntentFilter(MY_BROADCAST)
startMyBroadCase(); // call BroadCase to start
```

**In startMyBroadCase() function...**

```
private void startMyBroadCase() {
        Intent powerBroadCaseIntent = new Intent(MY_BROADCAST);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(powerBroadCaseIntent);
    }
```

But code does not working

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

For Manully Killing The Android App On Any Event